# How do you save a password within a framework so that it's hidden from whatever app imports it?

Tags: swift, frameworks, keychain

I have a framework that has some view controllers that have login screens.  Ideally, I would like to be able to securely store and remember people's passwords, probably for use with bio-authentication.  However, the apps that will import the framework should NOT have access to these passwords.  How can this be done?

I'm under the impression that if you save the passwords with keychain, the parent app will be able to recover them, but please correct me if I'm wrong, or if there's a way around this.

Comment: I hope you don't plan to store plaintext passwords. Properly encrypt with a salt and only store the result.

Comment: @rmaddy what's the best way to store a password to use with bio-authentication?  don't you need some sort of symmetric encryption?

Comment: @AlexBeals Why symmetric encryption? Why not a one-way hash algorithm like MD5?

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't sound like you should be building an app that stores security- or privacy critical data. Did you think, for instance, about how long clear-text passwords reside in memory? Do some serious research on how to deal with passwords first. [security.SE] is a great resource for that!

Comment: @ebby94 Because [that's not secure (enough)](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/41945).

Comment: MD5's not a good one way hash, but that's besides the case. @Raphael, I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do (or maybe I'm very wrong).  I feel like I need symmetric encryption so that I can recover the plaintext password, to pass through the login again if you're logging in with biometrics.  I can't just save a hashed password, I need to save user credentials to re-auth with.